# How to correctly manage Entities in Hibernate that 2 of them inherit after one

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, inheritance

i got a quick question. I am trying to make data as following:
Auth(email,pass) -> Client(name, surname, ...)
Auth(email,pass) -> RepairShop(nip, location, ...)

Auth

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)

public class Auth {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long authid;
```

Client

```
@Entity
public class Client extends Auth{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idClient;
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    private RepairShop repairShop;
```

RepairShop

```
@Entity
public class RepairShop extends Auth{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idRepairShop;
    ...
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "repairShop")
    private Set<Client> clients;
```

With repositories looking like
AuthRepository

```
public interface AuthRepository extends JpaRepository<Long, Auth>{

}
```

ClientRepository

```
public interface ClientRepository extends JpaRepository<Client,Long> {
}
```

RepairShopRepository

```
public interface RepairShopRepository extends JpaRepository<RepairShop, Long> {
}
```

Auth cannot be abstract class, this is only table to have good auth in my project
(currently i have just manually added table with some triggers to write data from Client and RepairShop to Auth, but i am looking for better solution)

My goal is to have database like
Auth
idauth
email
pass
role

Client
idclient
name
surname
idauth

RepairShop
idrepairShop
nip
location
idauth

Is it even possible to do it like follows? Or it is just bad idea and i should just use onetoone relationship and dont even play like this. Or maybe there is some better solution in database structure. Also it is important to let it easily work with Angular App to easily have access from logging with data from auth to managing other properties from Client/RepairShop tables

I think problem here lies in my repository config but im not sure.

What do you think about it?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the client->auth and repairship -> auth relationship from OOP perspective it is a has-a relationship rather than is-a relatioship. So, onetoone is the best way to map it.

```
@Entity 
public class Client extends Auth{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idClient;
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    private RepairShop repairShop;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="idauth")
    private Auth auth;
```

repair shop

```
@Entity
    public class RepairShop extends Auth{
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long idRepairShop;
        ...
        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "repairShop")
        private Set<Client> clients;
        @OneToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="idauth")
        private Auth auth;
```